# How to change site-wide jQuery slideUp/slideDown duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to adjust the default slideUp() and slideDown() duration in jQuery?  I have a site which has a bunch of slideUp/slideDown calls and I'd like to change their duration site-wide.  The only options I can find:

- Regex search and replace across all of my JS code. Possible, and I can insert a variable to change the duration again later.  But it would be more convenient if there were a jQuery setting, especially to reduce testing time.
- Edit jQuery itself. Not a viable option for maintenance reasons.

Comment: As another option: unless there's a duration setting explicitly used in your code, maybe you could modify jQuery JS file directly and set duration there. The default is 400 (see [link](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)). Maybe you could change to smth else.

Comment: It's not worth patching jquery itself for maintenance reasons. This is too minor a change for the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override them like:

```
$.prototype.slideDown = (function(slideDown){
    var defaultSpeed = 2000;
    return function(speed){
        slideDown.call( this, speed || defaultSpeed );
    };
})($.prototype.slideDown);
```

Then just do the same with the slideup function:

```
$.prototype.slideUp = (function(slideUp){
    var defaultSpeed = 2000;
    return function(speed){
        slideUp.call( this, speed || defaultSpeed );
    };
})($.prototype.slideUp);
```

Then just call it:

```
$('#whatever').slideUp();
```

Just make sure to override them before you start using them.

Comment: Edited to allow you to still specify a duration, but otherwise fall back on the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default animation speed like this:

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
```

**Important Note:** I think this will change the default speed for every jQuery animation, which may not be ideal in this case.